# Programatically Rotate Head in cardboard-java App

Tags: google-cardboard

I want to move about in the cardboard-java app programatically.

It is like I want the user feel constantly rotating on the floor but he might also move his head around whenever he wants.

I am new at this and know nothing about Unity. So please guide me what should I do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Save the following script as

> Rotator.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour {

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0,30,0) * Time.deltaTime);    
    }
}
```

Apply *Rotator.cs* script to you **CardboardMain** Gameobject. Bingo!!

Modify the values in vector3 in transform.Rotate as per your **CardboardMain** rotation.